# Prevent extraction of data to external system from within the ACCESS

Tags: security, extract, piracy-prevention

I'm developing a small MS Access 2007-2010 database with personal details and need to prevent the extraction of table from this database into any other database.

1) does that objective have to be done from within SQL and have the MDBS link to protected SQL tables

2) Can the import from my database be prevented from within Access.

Comment: Can you describe the attack vector in much more detail?

Comment: Any external MS Access database can import into itself the data and macros etc...  from another MS Access database.
The purpose of the database is to hold contact data of entities, from at least 5 groups and their personal and their interaction with each other. The final database is intended for internal use but it is still important to protect contact details.

Comment: It is envisaged that multiple password accessible users will be using the database, from different stations across the internet on PC and possibly on android.

Comment: Using "MS Access over the internet" is in my opinion an extremely bad idea. Please rethink your architecture from the ground up. Based on what you write it seems to me you actually want to build a cloud system: for example a web application that will store the data for various groups separate from each other and only allow access to properly authenticated users.

Comment: BTW if any of the people are EU residents then the GDPR applies to you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation so you need to be extra careful about protecting that data lest you face serious fines.